# Как создать Haar Cascade (XML-файл) для использования в OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

1. Я знаю что нужно много отрицательных и положительных фото, они должны быть одного размера?
2. как на основе этих фото создать казкад?

Comment: http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967057/how-do-i-create-a-custom-haar-classifier